# UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries) in a Java due to recursive dependency

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I have a Java application that loads some DLLs from a specified folder at runtime using System.loadLibrary(). The application successfully loads all but one of the DLLs that it finds in the folder. In the case of the unsuccessful load, it reports the error:

> C:\myapp\lib\foo.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

I've opened foo.dll in DependencyWalker but it doesn't report any problems (it lists IESHIMS.DLL and WER.DLL as missing but these are warnings and as far as I know, these can be ignored). The dependency tree lists WSOCK32.DLL, KERNEL32.DLL and one other application specific DLL which is included in the lib folder (and which successfully loads).

My best guess is that foo.dll depends in turn on another DLL which is not present in my lib folder but I don't know how to get any further information about what this dependency is. Can anyone suggest a way of debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Dependency Walker searches for dependency libs also in the folder where the lib itself is. LoadLibrary doesn't do this. My guess is that when you load the dependency with LoadLibrary you do it with a full path and that's why it can be found and loaded but when you load the other lib it's not found.

Answer (score 0):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) has a profile mode. Use it to see which modules ultimately fail to load. You'll likely see failures for some that are eventually found since some modules are matched by attempting various prefixes and suffixes for the file name.

Be sure to use the 32-bit or 64-bit version that matches your executable (e.g., javaw.exe).

To understand the DLL search path, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.